# second Sunday is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

something wrong with the script, if you run the code snippet and select Sundays, you can see that every second Sunday is empty I do not know why can you help thanks

```js
$(function() {
  var weekStart = new Date(2017, 1, 27);
  var roster = ['work', 'off', 'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'off', 'work', 'work', 'work', 'off', 'off', 'work'];

  $('#date').datepicker({
    minDate: weekStart,
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var week = Math.floor(days / 7) % 2;
      $('#week').val(week + 1);
      $('#day').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
      $('#work').val(roster[week * 7 + date.getDay() - 1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="date"></p>
<p>Day: <input type="text" id="day"></p>
<p>week: <input type="text" id="week"></p>
<p>work: <input type="text" id="work"></p>
```

Comment: I can't see the issue - all Sundays appear fine for me in the date picker control.

Comment: What do you mean by empty? They all show for me in Chrome

Comment: the work textbox is empty on Sunday 03/05/2017 and not empty on Sunday 03/12/2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDay() return for Sunday 0 and you have your weeks as 0 or 1 so

```
week * 7 + date.getDay() - 1
```

return -1 as result and it does not get value from roster table.

so use

```
$('#work').val(roster[(week) * 7 + date.getDay()]);
```

Comment: how can I fix it

Comment: remove -1 from calculation

Comment: $('#work').val(roster[(week) * 7 + date.getDay() ]);

Comment: Now it works fine but I need to change the roster order. the first day in roster is Sunday, I wonder if I can get datepicker format dd-mm-yy and tha first day is Sunday

Comment: mark as correct answer and create separate question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 to week?

```
$('#work').val(roster[(week+1) * 7 + date.getDay() - 1]);
```